# Error to Code MimeType.pdf as its shows MimeType Not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.Pdf);
pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName("123");
```

This is the part of my code which is now working as it is showing `MimeType` Not defined

What should I do With this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing
MimeType.Pdf to MimeType.PDF

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type

Comment: Thank you it Actually worked and solve my problem

Comment: Glad to hear that, consider marking the answer as Accepted for the community members who may have the same problem in the future